# Github Network Graph - Meaning of pointing arrow in the following diagram

Tags: git, github, networking, graph, git-merge

I'm analyzing someone's Network Graph in Github and I have not been able to figure out what is going on in the 'development' branch in the following picture:

[image: Network Graph]

When the 'temp' branch is merged into 'development',  two blue arrows end up pointing towards the next commit dot.

What is going on here?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think this can happen, if someone forgets to pull first. Hopefully, you receive a good answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If your local branch is behind origin and you try to push your commit it will make you pull your changes. If you do `git pull --rebase` git will rebase your commit to look like it was created after latest commit in origin producing a nice branchless sequence of commits. If you just do `git pull` you can get a local merge and this way get a branch that looks like this.

Without access to git log that's my best guess of what happened.